Why `min-height: 100%` doesn't work inside flex-grow item?
Consider the following HTML+CSS:


<div style="min-height: 100vh; display: flex; flex-direction: column">
  <div style="flex-grow: 1; background-color: red;">
    <div style="min-height: 100%; background-color: blue;">
      Test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



The blue div should span the whole height of its parent (min-height: 100%), but instead it is sized automatically. Is there a way to span the div vertically without modifying its parent? (note that this example represents a part of more complex layout).

It will, if at all you change flex-grow:1; with Flex-flow:1;.
Setting flex items to flex-grow it set the flex item to take the width or height of its contents, because at this point flex-basis is set to auto instead of 0%.
